# angular 4 - Row styling in CDK data-table

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am trying to use cdk datatable with customized row view. But there is not enough information about how to accomplish this yet. I tried going through the source code, But couldn't get a grasp of how to do it. Basically I want to contain the data in a card for each row. How can I do this?

Comment: what does "Basically I want to contain the data in a card for each row" mean.Please post some code which you have tried

Comment: @vikk If you look at this `https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/b5fc68b90729e1fba835465bb55e29f87d47df3f/src/cdk/table/row.ts#L26`, they have defined a template how a row should be displayed. I want to customize this. Also see this plunk `https://plnkr.co/edit/hZSxiasJDuDSEeShtENx?p=preview`

Comment: git link is broken

Comment: updated link @vikk

Comment: still i am getting 404 error in git link and plunker isnt running

Comment: sorry I should have checked before pasting @vikk

Comment: How about adding a class that replicates the styling of md-card. Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CfDo12A7qkrqARQDWWx8?p=preview) and let me know what you think

Comment: @Nehal thanks for your simple solution.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `class` to `md-row` that replicates the styling of `md-card`.

css:

```
.card{
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

html:

```
 <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
          class="mat-elevation-z4 card">
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CfDo12A7qkrqARQDWWx8?p=preview)